# Web: Perfectly center content in middle, but have a div on top that doesn't push content down

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Just learning web dev with react, so apologies if this is a basic question, but there are so many ways to do things with CSS and I'm lost.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="top-app-bar">
    Top App Bar
  </div>
  <div class="center-content">
  Perfectly centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.main {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.top-app-bar {
  height: 20vmin;
  margin: 2vmin;
}

.center-content {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}
```

The css is mainly copied from create react app starter project

https://jsfiddle.net/2wz7dahq/

As you can see in the jsfiddle, having my content pushes my content down. I do not want my main content to be pushed down, I want it to be perfectly centered so if the screen is resized into any dimension it has no scroll bars or anything. This page should be a perfect single page app with no scrolling.

Comment: But what if the user resizes the app? How should it handle it? What if they make it small enough that everything can't fit on the screen?

Comment: @TheGrandJ in this case I'm okay with it. The content in the middle is essentially going to be one word like "Yes" or "No" and so I want it to be dead center.

Comment: perhaps use `absolute` positioning for the `.center-content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `absolute` positioning for the `.center-content` so that the `.top-app-bar` or any other elements/contents would not influence its position. As for the scrollbar, this appears because of the additional height generated by the margins. So the equation for your document height becomes: `100vh + 8px + 2vmin` where `8px` is the `body` margin coming from the user agent stylesheet & `2vmin` is the margin coming from user defined CSS for the element `.top-app-bar`.

For that you could do any of the following:

- Get rid of the margins
- Apply `overflow:hidden` CSS property to prevent the scrollbar view
- or Refactor `min-height` to factor in the margins, e.g., `min-height: calc(100vh - XXX)`

In this implementation, you need to use a higher `z-index` for the interactive elements (for example, `.top-app-bar`) if the `.center-content` is going to take up the entire viewport (primarily mentioning this because currently it is taking up the entire viewport in your code example) because technically, it is currently at the top of the Stacking Context. Alternatively, control `.center-content`'s `height` & `width` to not take up the entire viewport.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  background-color: #212121;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: silver;
}

.top-app-bar {
  height: 20vmin;
  margin: 2vmin;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.center-content {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top-app-bar">
    Top App Bar
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  <div class="center-content">
    Perfectly centered
  </div>
</div>
```

---

React Component Below (since this is tagged as `reactjs`):

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="top-app-bar">
        Top App Bar
      </div>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
      <div className="center-content">
        Perfectly centered
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  background-color: #212121;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: silver;
}

.top-app-bar {
  height: 20vmin;
  margin: 2vmin;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.center-content {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I think this gets me pretty much where I need to be. Thank you @95faf8e76605e973

Comment: Your welcome. Please take note of my `z-index`/Stacking Context explanation - I think it will be essential for this implementation